# Is there a printf for SQLite prepared statements?

Tags: c, sqlite

I am looking for a simple interface for prepared statements in c that follows the printf structure.

Something along the lines of:

```
sqlite3 *connection;
sqlite3_open("db", &connection);
char *id = "chacham15";
int count = 5;
ArrayList* results = sqlite3_preparef(connection, "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE id=%s AND count=%d ", id, count);
```

I was looking at documentation and couldnt find any similar functions. I would rather not rewrite the code if it exists, therefore, does anyone know of such a function? Any help is much appreciated. I know how I can implement this myself if necessary, Im just hoping that its not.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you researched varargs in C?

Comment: No, you'd have to write your own function.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The point of this function is that I want to use prepared statements, but wrap the internal functions in one easier to use function. I.e. the implementation of `sqlite3_preparef` would contain calls to the actual sqlite3_prepare functions.

Comment: When you write `ArrayList* results = ...`, don't you just want to do the prepare, exec and fetch-loop in one step? You should hide all in your own function.

Comment: @ott-- yeah but the fetch has to return results. The result is an ArrayList which contains arrays (1 array for each row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use snprintf() then sqlite3_prepare_v2().  If you want to write a wrapper function that does both, look up stdarg (to make a variadic function) and vsnprintf().